# Why is my loop infinite? I have tested with 91

Tags: c++

I am checking if a number is prime by only checking if any odd number from 3 up to its sqaure root is it's factor, once it has one then the number isn't prime. I don't understand why my loop is seemingly infinite.

I have added cout lines to see where there problem begins and it does not really show

```
int countFactors(int num)
{
    cout << "Inside prime\n";
    int factors = 0, x = 0, i;
    x = int(sqrt(num));
    for (i = 3; i <= x; i += 2)
    {
        cout << "Inside prime for \n";

        while(factors < 1)
        {
            cout << "Inside Prime while";
            if (num % i == 0)
            {
                factors++;
            }
        }
    }
    return factors;
}
```

I am expecting the function to receive any number from 19 upwards, check if it has any factor of odd numbers from 3, once the factor is found the loop exits because the number is NOT odd since 1 itself and an extra number are factors. the functions returns 0 for prime or 1 not prime.

Comment: Once you enter the while loop, if the if statement is false, nothing changes and it'll stay there

Comment: Because `num%i==0` is never `true` - so `factors` doesn't increment, thus it is always like `0 < 1` and the loop is not gonna terminate

Comment: This would be a great problem to investigate using a debugger - https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Your algorithm, will discover that 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128,... are all prime numbers, and few other numbers it shouldn't, by multiplying these numbers with primes that are bigger than them. such as 6 which you won't check at all since its sqrt is less than 3.

Comment: @AaronHayman like I mentioned the function receives only odd numbers from 19 upwards so that case won't be encountered

Comment: @B001ᛦ  thanks, I managed to seemy mistake, so I made the while loop outside the for and initialised another control variable for it and it work as charm

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
     int countFactors(int num)
     {
         int factors = 0, x=0, i,y=1;
        x = int(sqrt(num));
        while(y>0){
        for (i=3;i<=x;i+=2)
        {
            if (num%i==0)
                {
                    factors++;
                    y--;

                }

        }
        if(factors ==0)
           {
              y--;
           }
        }

        return factors;
    }
```

Comment: what it the purpose of your while loop? under what circumstance do you think this sequenge will need to run more than once? `factors` can return numbers larger than 1 which you indicated was not your intention.

Comment: @AaronHayman there is no way factors can return numbers larger than one, since the moment  `factors` becomes 1, y becomes 0 then the loop exits, that's the purpose of the `while (y>0)`

Comment: Test your function on `num=105`. The while condition is evaluated and if true the the statement is executed in full. The loop isn't interupted mid iteration. To do that you need to use `break`. Simplest though, is if you want to only output 0 or 1 then replace `factors++;` with `factors=1;`

Comment: @AaronHayman thanks, I picked that up, now my program is running in the required time